# How to migrate a question?

Tags: support, migration

How can I migrate any question between various Stack Exchange websites if it seems to be off-topic?

Comment: That's mod's job, so let them know.

Answer (score 5):

Flag for moderator attention. At the moment, migration paths to other Stack Exchange sites are not available to 3k users. 3k users can only migrate to here, Meta. With <3k rep, you can only flag anyway.

Comment: But if I want to migrate my own question, then is it possible?

Comment: @RD017 if it's your own question, why bother? Delete and repost

Comment: That is one option and I have done this before, but still I want to know that how to migrate my own question.

Comment: @RD017 You can not migrate any questions, only moderators can do that.

Comment: How can I become a moderator?

Comment: @RD017 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: @muru thanks for the link...

Comment: You aren't thinking of becoming a mod just to migrate questions are you?

Comment: what reputation is needed to obtain the said privilege ?

Comment: @rancho 3k, as repeatedly mentioned in the answer

Comment: "At the moment, migration paths to other Stack Exchange sites are not available to 3k users." - Your answer contradicts your comment

Comment: @rancho migration is available, paths aren't.

Comment: Totally confusing statement